# angularjs changing state issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my app.js StateProvider configuration setup like below:

State 'dashboard' contains the sidebar and top navigation bar and should be active when the state dashboard.home and dashboard.addclient is active.

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController'
        })
        .state('dashboard.home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .state('dashboard.addclient', {
            url: '/addclient',
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.addclient.html',
            controller: 'ClientsController'
        })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
});
```

The issue is when the user clicks on a link inside the dashboard page it calls a function which changes the state like below:

```
app.controller('DashboardController', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.AddClient = function () {
        $state.go('dashboard.addclient');
    }
});
```

But for some reason the URL that it is trying to call looks like:

http://localhost/dashboard/partials/dashboard.addclient.html

HTML:

Index contains a view which the Login will get loaded into:

```
<body>
    <div id="view" ui-view></div>
</body>
```

I so when the user logs in we have another ui-view on the dashboard:

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide your HTML also

Comment: @AKA I don't really know what HTML you need but added what i thought was necessary.

Comment: Your dashboard state should be abstract. Also, update the question and show us your links. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your template URLs are relative paths because they don't begin with '/'. This means that if your browser currently has http://localhost/dashboard in the address bar when you change your state to `dashboard.addclient` it'll just append your template url to the current address. Instead you can try this:

`.state('dashboard.addclient', {
  url: '/addclient',
  templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard.addclient.html',
  controller: 'ClientsController'
})`

Comment: Thanks for that! Been looking at this for days.